# Is the following DNN matrix CP?

Tags: linear-algebra

Is the following Doubly Non-negative matrix Completely Positive:

$\frac{1}{6}\begin{bmatrix} 2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\0 & 2 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\0 & 0 & 2 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\0 & 1 & 1 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 2 & 0 & 0\\1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 2 & 0\\1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 2\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: I don't know. What does "completely positive" mean?

Comment: It means that the above matrix can be expressed as $WW^T$ with all entries in the $W$ matrix non-negative. The $W$ matrix need not be square.

Comment: I think 6 times that matrix can be CP, with W being a 0-1 matrix.  Each column of W will have two 1's in it, and W can be divided into three groups of columns such that no row in each group has more than a single 1 in it.  This definitely resembles a combinatorial design problem.  Gerhard "Ask Me About Combinatorial Design" Paseman, 2011.07.28

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit: I wanted the following matrix to be $W$.  Robert Israel suggested
I call it $W^T$ instead.  I defer to his years of experience and the fact
that it gives a better answer to the problem.  End Edit.

For 6 times the given matrix, I nominate the following candidate for $W^T$

$$\begin{bmatrix}
1 &   &   &   & 1 &   &   &   & 1 \\\\
1 &   &   &   &   & 1 &   & 1 &   \\\\
  & 1 &   & 1 &   &   &   &   & 1 \\\\
  & 1 &   &   &   & 1 & 1 &   &   \\\\
  &   & 1 & 1 &   &   &   & 1 &   \\\\
  &   & 1 &   & 1 &   & 1 &   &  
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Does this help?

Gerhard "Ask Me About Binary Matrices" Paseman, 2011.07.28

Comment: I did this by hand, and left out the zeroes for readability.  I apologize conditionally for any errors in this answer.  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2011.07.28

Comment: Also (assuming the answer helps), I would like in return to know the motivation for the problem.  In particular, if I have helped to solve a homework problem, I want the grader to give me some of the credit.  Gerhard "Maintain A Good Credit Score" Paseman, 2011.07.28

Comment: Make that $W^T$ and you're correct.

Comment: @Gerhard Paseman, I am trying to show that the matrices resulting out of an optimization problem are CP. Although not all matrices will have the same structure as the one I posted. Definitely this is not a homework problem.

Comment: In my reading of the literature on 0-1 matrices, $G$ is a Gram matrix where $G = MM^T$ and $M$ is some special matrix  (for me a square 0-1 matrix, although the definition may be more general) .  I suggest looking at Gram matrix literature if you are going to deal with matrices like the one in your question.  Also, Will Orrick might be a good person to consult for more detail.  Gerhard "Ask Me Not About Transpose" Paseman, 2011.07.28

Comment: When I say that a matrix is doubly non-negative, it is implied that the matrix is a gram matrix and thus can be written in the form $G=MM^T$. What I am really concerned about is that such a factorization exists with non-negative $M$. This problem is still open for general matrices $G$, although for specific cases it is solved. I am hoping that the kind of matrices that I get fall into some specific category or can be derived from known results.

Comment: Pawan, I sometimes "enhance" answers (by adding what I think are relevant comments) for the benefit of the original poster and for future readers.  I apologize for any slight (regarding what you may know or may not know) I may have caused.  The problem reminds me of the search for 0-1 matrices with maximal determinant, and I thought that literature might be of use.  When you are ready to share more, I invite you to do so.  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2011.07.28